# Python pandas iterate through dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, bigdata

I am trying to work with Pandas and I need a solution for the following problem.

I have a dataset with columns that look like this:

```
X1 Y1 Z1 1.....(bunch of other columns)
X1 Y1 Z1 2.....(bunch of other columns)
X1 Y1 Z1 3.....(bunch of other columns)
X2 Y2 Z2 1.....(bunch of other columns)
X2 Y2 Z2 2.....(bunch of other columns)
X2 Y2 Z2 3.....(bunch of other columns)
X2 Y2 Z2 4.....(bunch of other columns)
```

I need to process the dataset by considering the first three columns as the key. So I need to first consider all rows associated with `X1 Y1 Z1`, process a bunch of columns in that and then move on to the next chunk `X2 Y2 Z2`. So first its

```
X1 Y1 Z1 1.....(bunch of other columns)
X1 Y1 Z1 2.....(bunch of other columns)
X1 Y1 Z1 3.....(bunch of other columns)
```

followed by

```
X2 Y2 Z2 1.....(bunch of other columns)
X2 Y2 Z2 2.....(bunch of other columns)
X2 Y2 Z2 3.....(bunch of other columns)
X2 Y2 Z2 4.....(bunch of other columns)
```

I am looking for a solution in pandas or numpy to process this dataset. And I deal with millions of rows, so pandas's `iterrows()` would be slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is loaded in to a DataFrame `df` with columns `X`, `Y`, `Z`, `col1`, `col2`...., then you could loop over 'groups'/'chunks' of the data as below:

```
for concat_XYZ, df_group in df.groupby(df['X']+df['Y']+df['Z']):
    # process df_group
    # ....
```

Each `df_group` is a chunk (or a DataFrame in itself) as you desire in your question. The concatenation of the strings in the `X`, `Y` and `Z` columns is used to uniquely identify a group.

Comment: the `df_group` contains the original dataframe that looks messed up

Comment: `df_group` will be a tuple of 2 elements. The first element is the concatenated string of the `X`, `Y` and `Z` columns. The second element is the sub-group/chunk that you wish to process. Edited the answer to separate the two elements in the `for` line.

Comment: `concat_XYZ` is now a string like `X1Y2Z2`, while `df_group` is now a DataFrame/chunk you process.

Comment: This is what I did, and so far it seems to work ok..

`def func1():
  df_grouped = df.groupby(df['X'] + df['Y'] + str(df['Z']))
  for d in df_grouped:
      list_of_items = d[1]['col4'].get_values().tolist()
      processList(list_of_items)

def processList(self, list_of_items):
   # process the list_of_items`

Answer (score 1):

If your processing is identical but you need to separate them by groups, then write your function and use `groupby.apply()` it will return the dataframe after applying your function group wise.

```py
def do_stuff(DataFrame):
    DataFrame['stuff'] = DataFrame['col1'] + DataFrame['col2'] + DataFrame['col3']
    return DataFrame

new_df = original_df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], as_index=False).apply(do_stuff)
```